# Google wallet generic pass upcoming notification

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, integration, wallet, google-wallet

I have integrated google wallet api with my .net core web app , the pass is displaying properly , but I need to know how to use the upcoming notification feature in the generic pass , I tried to understand it from the google wallet generic pass official documentation but it's not clear and I didn't get it .
If please anyone can clear up the things to me .

I tried to set enable notifications to true , but didn't work .

Comment: Google Wallet sends a notification to the user three hours prior to the event. The event time is defined by `class.dateTime.start`. You need to pay attention to the time node and whether [the notification is actually enabled](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079661).

Comment: Thanks, @Chen for your reply, do you know if I can customize the notification itself, I mean if I can change the notification message?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/wallet/tickets/events/use-cases/upcoming-notification), notifications are in an unmodifiable format. But the message is not sure if it can be modified, I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Ali Dbouk I'm new about google service. I've to create Google Generic Pass (https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/resources/pass-builder) using C#. I request you please guide me how I've to start? Its really very important for me. I've read relected docs but getting from where I've to start